# How to implement equivalent of model.where { |m| m.arr.include? x }

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So, I realized that Rails does not support passing blocks to functions on model. How should I retrieve all objects with an array attribute that includes some given element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of the `where` method is to add a `WHERE` clause to the SQL query generated by ActiveRecord — it does not perform any filtering on the results:

```
Post.                        # initializes query:  SELECT * FROM `posts`
  where(author_id: 42).      # adds:  WHERE `posts`.`author_id` = 42
  to_a                       # <-- it's only here that the query is executed
```

If you *must* filter the result set using a block, you have to execute your query *first* to get the results in an array, and then use the `select` method to filter that array:

```
Post.all.                            # SELECT * FROM `posts`
  to_a.                              # <-- executes query, returns the results in an array
  select { |p| p.arr.include?(x) }   # filter array
```

Obviously, this is going to be *very slow* if you have a lot of records, since your app has to fetch every record from the database, deserialize their array attributes and check each one for the filter criteria.

---

Documentation links:

- **[ActiveRecord::QueryMethods#where](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where)**
- **[Enumerable#select](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-select)**

Comment: I'm very new to database and sql. Do you mind also sharing about how slow such queries can be, given that there are 1e4, 1e5, or perhaps more records?

Comment: @zetta: very slow. So slow that you don't want to do this. "I have enough time to eat lunch" kind of slow.

Comment: @zetta Ok, maybe have a coffee, not lunch. But you get the idea :)

Comment: @zetta If you have more than a 100 records or so, then this approach likely won't work. Can you post more details about your database structure and what you are storing in the array attribute? These array values seem like something that should be put in a separate table.

Comment: @MátéSolymosi it's only an attribute called "categories" on posts. I need to get 8 random posts for whichever appointed category. Does it mean that I'd better create another model "Category", to store ids of posts that are included?